# How to avoid a callback in promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I am new to NodeJS and JavaScript. I am badly stuck in a problem: 
I want to generate QR image of 'some text' and after generating it, I want to query my MySQL database and insert the image to database.
Problem is that `QRCode.toDataURL` of `SOLDAIR` module goes in running state and query is called before the QR image is returned from the `.toDataUrl` function.
Hence it results in error.

I tried everything, promises, nested promises, counters, if statements etc., but I am unable to find a solution.

My code:

```
router.post('/generateTicket', (req,res) => {
  const query1 = `SELECT * FROM booking ORDER BY  bookingID DESC LIMIT 1`;
  const query2 = `INSERT INTO ticket (ticket_image,BookingID) SET ?`;
  let bookingID;
  let count;
  let ticket_data = {};
  Promise.using(mysql.getSqlConn(), conn => {
    conn.query(query1).then(resultOfQuery1 => {
      bookingID = resultOfQuery1[0].BookingID;
      count = resultOfQuery1[0].PeopleCount;

      console.log("ID = " + bookingID + " people count = "+count);

      promiseToCreateQRcode().then(function (URLfromResolve) {
        console.log("the url is " + URLfromResolve );
      }).catch(function (fromReject) {
        console.log("Rejected "+ fromReject);
      }); // catch of promise to create QR

    }).catch(err => {
      res.json({ status: 500, message: 'Error Occured in query 1 ' + err });
    }); // catch of query 1
  });
});


var opts = {
  errorCorrectionLevel: 'H',
  type: 'image/png',
  rendererOpts: {
    quality: 0.3
  }
};

let promiseToCreateQRcode = function () {
  let QRImage;
  return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    QRCode.toDataURL('text', function (err, url) {
    if (err) throw err
      console.log("\n"+url+"\n");
      QRImage = url;
    });

    if (QRImage)
      resolve(QRImage);
    else
      reject("error occured in url");
  });
};
```

As u can see, the program jumps to if statement and the QR image is not generated yet, hence it goes in "reject":

[image]

Comment: I never came across something as Promise.using() .

Comment: @SatishKumar, [`Promise.using()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.using.html) is a static method of Bluebird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
let promiseToCreateQRcode = function () {
return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    QRCode.toDataURL('text', function (err, url) {
        if (err){
          reject(err); // or some message
        } else {
           resolve(url);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

This way promise will be resolved only when **toDataURL** returns QR image.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572). You need to call `resolve` or `reject` in the asynchronous callback!

```
function promiseToCreateQRcode() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        QRCode.toDataURL('text', function (err, url) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log("\n"+url+"\n");
                resolve(url);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Using this extra `QRImage` variable like you did [cannot work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572).